# submit multiple forms one by one using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit multiple forms one by one and I'm working with php and jquery. 
I have two or multiple forms with values, and when I click add button, first form should display in a popup window with the entered values and a submit button.

When I click submit in the popup window, first form should be submitted and second form should be displayed in the popup window.

How should I do this?

```
<div id="whole">
<form id="frm1"><table><tr><td>
<label>Title : </label>
<input id="frm1title1" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Descr  : </label>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="frm1desc1"></textarea></td></tr></table>
</form>

<hr>
<form id="frm2">
<table><tr><td><label>Title : </label>
<input id="frm2title2" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Descr  : </label>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="frm2desc2"></textarea></td></tr></table>
</form>

<input type="button" value="add">
</div>
```

Comment: Additionally, popup windows are super-annoying. Please use AJAX and inline "windows" instead. (Have a look at jQuery UI dialogs)

Answer (score -1):

take a look at Jquerys [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) api ... bind the submit button to submit all the forms..

something like this

replace your

```
<input type="button" value="add">
```

with

```
<input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="add">
```

then JS as follows:

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
$("#frm1").submit();
$("#frm2").submit();
});
```